# how to swap lines in a string builder using java

Tags: java, string, logic, backend, stringbuilder

lets say I have a string builder of something like:

```
StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();
content.append("line 1 content...");
content.append("line 2 content...");
content.append("line 3 content...");
content.append("line 4 content...");
content.append("line 5 content...");
System.out.Println(content.toString());
```

and the output is:

```
line 1 content
line 2 content
line 3 content
line 4 content
line 5 content
```

Now how do swap line 3 with line 2? so that the final output should look like:

```
line 1 content
line 3 content
line 2 content
line 4 content
line 5 content
```

I used `String[] splitContent = content.toString().split("\n");`

and when I do `splitContent.length()`, it shows as 5.

Any help/suggestion is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: A StringBuilder has no concept of lines. Unless each line has exactly the same number of characters you would need to parse the builder to find the offsets of each line and then do the swap. An `ArrayList` would probably be a better class to use. Each item in the list can represent a line.

Comment: Use the other `StringBuilder`methods, such as `indexOf` and `replace`.  But what is the real use case that needs this?  What is stopping the original `append`s from being called in the expected order?

Comment: I would use a array list to store the lines.  Then use one StringBuilder to construct the first output and another StringBuilder to construct the second output.  Otherwise, you can always manipulate StringBuilder the way you manipulate a string using indexOf, insert, replace.

Answer (score 1):

For this case, an `ArrayList` may be a better class than `StringBuilder`.

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Swap {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> content = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
                 "line one...",
                 "line two...",
                 "line three...",
                 "line four..."
        ));

        System.out.println(content);
        Collections.swap(content, 1, 2);
        System.out.println(content);

    }
}
```

### Output

```
[line one..., line two..., line three..., line four...]
[line one..., line three..., line two..., line four...]
```

Comment: hey thanks for your input. but here's the thing. the reason I opted for string builder is that, the content is dynamic, and I only wanted to swap the 2's and 3's. so the output is like:
`line one`
`line two`
`line three`
`line four`
`line one`
`line two`
`line three`
`line four`
and now the output should like:
`line one`
`line three`
`line two`
`line four`
`line one`
`line three`
`line two`
`line four`
Im sorry if I confused you.